# Python email attachment is not decoding

Tags: python, email, encoding

I am trying to send a email attachment from a string of text instead of a external file, but the attachment did not decode at the receiving end. I encoded the attachment in base64 using the built-in string encode function. I have seen many examples for attaching a external file, but i have not seen a example for sending a string as a attachment.

why didn't the attachment decode at the receiving end? am i improperly encoding the attachment?

```
attachment = MIMEText("This is a test".encode('base64', 'strict'))
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', 'test.txt')           
msg.attach(attachment)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use `base64`, you should set the encoding explicitly:

```
attachment = MIMEText("This is a test".encode('base64', 'strict'))
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='test.txt')           
attachment.replace_header('content-transfer-encoding', 'base64')
msg.attach(attachment)
```

If you don't really need `base64`, just let the library decide for you:

```
attachment = MIMEText("This is a test")
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='test.txt')           
msg.attach(attachment)
```

---

Or, use `email.encoders.encode_base64` :

```
attachment = MIMEText("This is a test")
email.encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='test.txt')           
msg.attach(attachment)
```

Answer (score 0):

you may refer to http://docs.python.org/2/library/email.mime.html?highlight=mimetext#email.mime.text.MIMEText and use

```
email.mime.text.MIMEText(_text[, _subtype[, _charset]])
```

with  `_subtype` the default `plain` and _charset stating explicitly your encoding.